# How to sort two arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to sort these 2 arrays in Java:

```java
new int[]{15, 15, 26, 46}, //value

new int[]{50, 20, 15, 25}, //quantity
```

I want them to be sorted by value from lowest to highest but if they have the same value I want them to be sorted by quantity then the one with lower quantity will go first, with that in mind I am expecting this result:

```
{2,1,3,4}
```

Comment: This looks like homework.  Have you tried writing any Java code yet, and, if so, can you include that in your question?

Comment: Please read about custom comparator. Try writing one. Add the code what you've tried and let us know if you need any more help with it.

Comment: The best way to do this is to create a class that stores `value` and `quantity` then sort an array of class objects.